# optimize query with lambra expression in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity

I have the following query, often have excution timeout errors, have any ideas for optimization.
Thank you!

```
queryResult = db.Products
                            .Where(x => !x.product_is_deleted)
                            .Where(x => x.product_name.Contains(keyword) || x.product_barcode.Contains(keyword) || x.ProductType.pro_type_name.Contains(keyword) || x.ProductType.pro_type_name.Contains(keyword))
                            .Select(x => new ProductView
                            {
                                product_id = x.product_id,
                                product_barcode = x.product_barcode,
                                product_name = x.product_name,
                                product_unit = x.product_unit,
                                product_size = x.product_size,
                                product_weight = x.product_weight,
                                product_type_id = x.product_type_id,
                                product_inventory = shelf == 0 ? (x.ImportProductDetails.Where(y => y.imp_pro_detail_product_id == x.product_id && y.ImportProduct.import_pro_warehouse_id == warehouse_id ).Select(y => y.imp_pro_detail_inventory).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()) : (x.ImportProductDetails.Where(y => y.imp_pro_detail_product_id == x.product_id && y.ImportProduct.import_pro_warehouse_id == warehouse_id  && y.imp_pro_detail_shelf_id == shelf).Select(y => y.imp_pro_detail_inventory).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()),
                                product_opening_stock = x.product_opening_stock,
                                product_type_name = x.ProductType.pro_type_name,
                                product_price = x.ProductPrices.Where(y => !y.proprice_is_deleted).Where(y => y.proprice_applied_datetime <= DateTime.Now).OrderByDescending(y => y.proprice_applied_datetime).Select(y => y.proprice_price).FirstOrDefault(),
                                product_discount_type = x.ProductDiscounts.Where(y => !y.pro_discount_is_deleted && y.pro_discount_start_datetime <= datetimeNow && y.pro_discount_end_datetime >= datetimeNow).OrderByDescending(y => y.pro_discount_id).Select(y => y.pro_discount_type).FirstOrDefault(),
                                product_discount_value = x.ProductDiscounts.Where(y => !y.pro_discount_is_deleted && y.pro_discount_start_datetime <= datetimeNow && y.pro_discount_end_datetime >= datetimeNow).OrderByDescending(y => y.pro_discount_id).Select(y => y.pro_discount_value).FirstOrDefault()
                                //product_norm_name = x.ProductionNorms.Where(y => y.pro_norm_name == x.product_id && y.pro_norm_is_applied == true).Select(y => y.pro_norm_id).FirstOrDefault()
                            });
```

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to view the query that gets generated, execute the query in SQL Server Management Studio and look at the execution costs of each step, look if you can add indexes on columns to speed up certain steps.

Comment: thanks! i had add indexes on column. the query that gets generated is very long